# CONCAT in WHERE clause of SELECT statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

M2014 is a text field in the DB table.

This statement works correctly (returns count = 368)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM arealist WHERE M2014 = 'Yes'
```

However, I having problems with this statement (returns count = 0) All I have changed
is the concat

```
SELECT count(*) FROM arealist WHERE concat('M','2014') = 'Yes'
```

What could be the cause and solution?

Comment: `concat('M','2014')` is a string. M2014 is a column name

Comment: `CONCAT` returns a string, so you are comparing `'M2014'` to `'Yes'`, and those don't match

Comment: You are actually getting all the rows where 'M2014' = 'Yes'

Comment: in first query M2014 is a field[column] in the table and in second its a string comparing with another M2014=Yes that will never return a count

Comment: Purpose of the query is to get a count of all M2014 = Yes  The first statement is the correct answer 368.  I am trying to replace the fixed 2014 with a variable so I can make the query more flexible.

Comment: Do you want to get the column name dynamically? How do you want to generate the M2014?

Comment: In the first query M2014 is a column name and is part of a where clause to find where M2014 = Yes;  I am trying to duplicate this same idea in the second query's where clause

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing two strings in the second SELECT statement. The second statement is appending two strings 'M' and '2014' which results in the query comparing 'M2014' to 'Yes' two strings, not the value of the column. Making a statement like this:

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM AreaList 
WHERE M2014 = CONCAT('Y','es')

That statement would return 368 rows. What are you ultimately trying to do with this statement?

Comment: Purpose of the query is to get a count of all M2014 = Yes The first statement is the correct answer 368. I am trying to replace the fixed 2014 with a variable so I can make the query more flexible. The column name in part is the year so I would like down the line to be able to substitute a variable for the year portion of the column name.

Comment: So how can I get a more flexible column name?

Comment: Not sure what references that table for you, but here's what I would do:

1. Add a column named "Calendar Year" NVARCHAR(4).
2. Then have a column that stores 'yes'.
3. Store the year value in that column.
4. Refer to the below sql

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM AreaList
Where CalendarYear = '2014'
AND "YourYesColumn" = 'Yes'

Comment: I am not sure I get this at all - I think I am just substituting the concat expression for the column name (M2014) in the where clause.  If not that, then what am I doing?

Comment: The concat function takes strings, and returns a single string. The concat function will not return a column value.

Comment: Then my question is how to get a column name = to M2014 in that spot of the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate a dynamic column name for the where clause in MySQL. There are a number of Stack Overflow articles to that effect. Normally, I would arrange my data so that there was some sort of date or timestamp associated with the row, rather than using date specific columns. (I'm assuming M2014 has something to do with the year 2014). When arranged this way you can select what you need based on whatever date requirements you have.

That said, if your data model is fixed, then you're best bet is probably to use another language, C#, python, whatever, to create the column names you need dynamically and then send the entire query to MySQL. Alternatively, you could write a series of SQL statements, one for date column you're interested in.

The following query in google turned up a number of relevant results: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=dynamic+column+names+in+sql&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&safe=active#channel=suggest&q=dynamic+column+names+in+mysql+where+clause&safe=active

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in php like that

```
  $year = 2014;

   SELECT count(*) FROM arealist 
   WHERE M$year = 'Yes'
```